# Python equivalent to the MATLAB function "ischange"

Tags: python, matlab

Does anyone know if a Python function equivalent to the MATLAB function [ischange](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ischange.html).

I'm simply trying to extract the flat part of the curve in the following data.

[image]

I've tried numpy.diff which gives noisy results.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to contain both your MATLAB and Python code. `ischange()` is a 700 line high-level function with loads of functionality. Translating the entirety of that is way too broad for Stack Overflow. Helping you to find/translate the specific options you used in MATLAB, on the other hand, might be OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy.diff with `.round()` added at the end, to get rid of noise, as I see your noise happens to be less than 0.5.

Comment: Thank you! That almost worked. np.round(np.diff(y)/np.diff(x)) still gave a tiny bit of noise, so running a smoothing algorithm over that data gave robust segmentation of the flat region.

Comment: Of course that depends on how you define "change" on the plot, but by dividing np.diff(x), you state that you want 5 times more precision. i.e. if 0.1 change happens in y, you count that as a change. If you would like to count `x` as a considerable change, you should substitute `np.diff(x)` with `2*x`. Hence the difference between "noise" and "considerable change" will be up to you.